# Decompiling Anonymous Method IL in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, decompiling

I have this method

```
public void Add(Action<Cursor> action)
{
    // Decompile `action` to C#
}
```

Inside the method I want to decompile the anonymous method inside `action`  to C# code, or AST representation of C# code.

I tried using `Mono.Cecil` and `ICSharpCode.Decompiler` (from the [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) repository), but I couldn't find a way to decompile anonymous methods, as both libraries require you to load the assembly from a physical location and search the method through the types graph, which seems very convoluted, especially when looking for an anonymous method.

Is there a way use the IL Byte array of the method, and decompile that to C#?

```
public void Add(Action<Cursor> action)
{
    var il = action.Method.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();
    var ast = decompiler.DecompileIL(il); // Does such decompiler exist?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `ICSharpCode.Decompiler` library (from the [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) repository), I was able to decompile a lambda method.

Like this

```
public void Add(Action<Cursor> action)
{
    // Get the assembly in which the lambda resides
    var asm = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
    var file = asm.Location;

    // Create a resolver (a callback for resolving referenced assemblies during decompilation)
    var resolver = new CustomAssemblyResolver(asm);
    // Create an instance of decompiler
    var decompiler = new CSharpDecompiler(file, resolver, new DecompilerSettings());

    // Get an "EntityHandle" instance for the lambda's underlying method
    var method = MetadataTokenHelpers.TryAsEntityHandle(action.Method.MetadataToken); 

    var ast = decompiler.Decompile(new List<EntityHandle>() { method.Value });
}
```

As I mentioned, you provide the `CSharpDecompiler` instance with a resolver (`IAssemblyResolver`) whose job is to load referenced assemblies during the decompilation process.

`ICSharpCode.Decompiler` has a `UniversalAssemblyResolver` ([source](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/blob/master/ICSharpCode.Decompiler/Metadata/UniversalAssemblyResolver.cs))
which does the job by searching common folders in the file system (it receives a framework version to know where to search).  I didn't like it as it assumes too much and requires too much information (I don't always know the framework or other parts of my runtime), so I've created my own resolver which traverses the assemblies graph (starting from the calling assembly).

```
class CustomAssemblyResolver : IAssemblyResolver
{
    private Dictionary<string, Assembly> _references;

    public CustomAssemblyResolver(Assembly asm)
    {
        _references = new Dictionary<string, Assembly>();
        var stack = new Stack<Assembly>();
        stack.Push(asm);

        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var top = stack.Pop();
            if (_references.ContainsKey(top.FullName)) continue;

            _references[top.FullName] = top;

            var refs = top.GetReferencedAssemblies();
            if (refs != null && refs.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (var r in refs)
                {
                    stack.Push(Assembly.Load(r));
                }
            }
        }

        ;
    }

    public PEFile Resolve(IAssemblyReference reference)
    {
        var asm = _references[reference.FullName];
        var file = asm.Location;
        return new PEFile(file, new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), PEStreamOptions.Default, MetadataReaderOptions.Default);
    }

    public PEFile ResolveModule(PEFile mainModule, string moduleName)
    {
        var baseDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(mainModule.FileName);
        var moduleFileName = Path.Combine(baseDir, moduleName);
        if (!File.Exists(moduleFileName))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Module {moduleName} could not be found");
        }
        return new PEFile(moduleFileName, new FileStream(moduleFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), PEStreamOptions.Default, MetadataReaderOptions.Default);
    }
}
```

I don't know if it's the best approach for all use cases, but It works great for me, at least so far.

Comment: Might not be the best way to do this, but this also helped me when I needed to get the AST of an arbitrary function from a file based on the metadata token. I didn't need to implement the custom resolver in this case.

Comment: @Plutoberth in my case I was working with external libraries and NuGet packages and I needed to get the metadata of those. might have been a better way to do it though.. maybe I could be more selective about what I resolve.

Comment: If you're going to post C# code, please follow C# coding conventions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions